# Laravel get translated validation errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, translation

I use Laravel 5.1, I want to return translated validation error in this request class. Please any help how to return translated data.

```
class ContactRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install this package : [laravel langs](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang)
(Copy languages folders you wish integrate into resources/lang)

Change locale variable in config/app to 'ru' for example, and that's all :)

Answer (score 11):

In the `resources/lang/en` folder, there is a file named `validation.php`. Put the translated error messages in the file as described in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-customizing-the-error-messages).

How your `ru/validation.php` file should look (but with russian text):

```
return [
    'required' => ':attribute is required',
    'email'    => 'You need to enter a valid :attribute',
    'captcha'  => 'This :attribute is invalid'
]
```

Comment: I've two language directories en and ru, validation.php have both folders I want to get translated errors.

Comment: @GeorgeKhachidze Don't forget to call `App::setLocale($locale);`

Comment: I call but it return me default language errors even i choose another.

Comment: So can you show a example how get translated errors.

Comment: You need to set the messages in the `ru/validation.php` file for the validation rules you are using (eg. required, captcha, email) have you read the documentation I linked?

Comment: @GeorgeKhachidze I've changed my answer to better illustrate what you need to do